# Change data order data frame R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with the following structure:

```
variable_1<-rep("one",times=8) 
variable_2<-c("one","one","two","two","three","three","four","four")
actual<-c(0,10,0,20,0,30,0,40)
predicted<-c(10,0,20,0,30,0,40,0)

data_1<-data.frame(cbind(variable_1,variable_2,actual,predicted))
```

I would like to shift the columns to obtain a data frame with the following structure:

```
variable_1_new<-rep("one",times=4)
variable_2_new<-c("one","two","three","four")
actual_new<-c(10,20,30,40)
predicted_new<-c(10,20,30,40)

data_2<-data.frame(cbind(variable_1_new,variable_2_new,actual_new,predicted_new))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that your data is read in the **correct format: Strings not factors**

You can do this by **removing cbind**

```
data_1<-data.frame(variable_1,variable_2,actual,predicted)
```

or by setting the **flag stringsAsFactors** to **false**

```
data_1<-data.frame(cbind(variable_1,variable_2,actual,predicted),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

To be able to calculate the sums of your columns actual and predicted, you first must **convert** the columns **to numeric**

```
data_1$actual <- as.numeric(data_1$actual)
data_1$predicted <- as.numeric(data_1$predicted)
```

The **columnwise sums** are calculated using **aggregate**

```
sums <- aggregate(data_1[c("actual","predicted")], data_1[c("variable_1","variable_2")], sum)
```

Finally, you need to change the order

```
data_2 <- sums[order(sums$actual),]
```